# Connection reset by peer in Raspberrypi?

Tags: ubuntu

I cant seem to ssh into my raspberrypi

I get an output
Connection reset by 192.168.1.101 port 22

Now I have tried the command

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_* && sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

but it doesnt seem to work 
I still get the same error